# How to mount a Google Drive directory locally?

Tags: mount, google-drive

I want to store backups to my Google Drive account.

I want to mount Google drive so that I can  copy folders in there and it gets saved in my Google drive.

I have [read this](http://www.linuxtechi.com/mount-google-drive-in-ubuntu/), but since I don't have any GUI installed, is not possible for me to use the Grive interphase.

Comment: You can replace most of `zenity` entries for `dialog` in the grive-setup script and see what happens.